# Order of catch statement?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

In `try`-`catch` syntax, does it matter in what order catch statements for `FileNotFoundException` and `IOExceptipon` are written?

Comment: One way compiles, the other doesn't. I suggest you try it. ;)

Comment: It is also worth noting that if you want to handle `FileNotFoundException` and `IOException` the same way anyway, you can catch them both in the same block (providing you are using Java SE 7 and above) by using `catch(FileNotFoundException|IOException ex)` [See this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)

Comment: @Deco `FileNotFoundException` **is an** `IOException`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The FileNotFoundException is inherited from the IOException. Exception's subclasses have to be caught first.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, Specific exception should be written first, broader after that,

Its like you call all the animals first in the room and after you try to see if there is any human outside

**For example**

```
try{
  //do something
}catch(Exception ex){

}catch(NullPointerException npe){

}
```

Will give you compile time error

Answer (score 7):

Specific Exceptions must be caught prior to general exception or else you will get an unreachable code error.
For example -

```
try{
  //do something
}catch(NullPointerException npe){

}catch(NumberFormatException nfe){

}catch(Exception exp){

}
```

If you put the `Exception` catch block before the `NullPointerException` or `NumberFormatException` catch block, you will get a compile time error. (Unreachable code).

Answer (score 2):

On a tangent, I would advise you to think twice whether you need all those catch blocks in the first place. Are you sure you are going to provide meaningful handling for each case differently? If you are just going to print out a message, you can only catch `IOException` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

well...start from subclasses to superclass...that's the ideal way..otherwise you will get **unreachable code error**

Answer (score 0):

Yes Of Course. The more specific exception should be written in the first catch block and the generic exceptions like `catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}` should be written in the final set of catch block.

**If you try the other way then, your specific exception will be unreachable by the JVM compiler!**

Answer (score 0):

`IOException` is the super class of `FileNotFoundException`. So, if you put the **catch** statement for `IOException` above that for `FileNotFoundException`, then the code for second catch will become unreachable and the compiler will throw an `error` for that. Reason is simple: `every object of a sub class can be easily accepted by a super class reference`.

Answer (score 0):

**IOException is the super class of FileNotFoundException .So fist catch sub class i.e FileNotFoundException and then you need to catch IOException**

*For Example,*

```
try{
      // something
   } catch(FileNotFoundException fne){
      // Handle the exception here
   } catch(IOException ioe) {
      // Handle the IOException here
   }
```